# Why not accepting a theory that has obvious advantages, like the rishon model?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Already in 1981, Haim Harari invented the [Rishon model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishon_model) of elementary particles. It provides a natural way to accommodate the known elementary particles and reduces the number of elementary ones to the most economical number of two.
The two particles are the T-rishon, with a unit electrical charge of -1/3, a unit hyper color charge, and a unit color charge. The weak force is thought to be a residual force and the Higgs field is thought to be a normal field (instead of a false vacuum field). On top of that, there is no asymmetry between matter and anti-matter. All observed matter is thought to be composed of equal amounts of matter and anti-matter (this leads to the new question of why the observed matter is not composed out of their anti manifestations, containing exactly the same rishons, but alas). All particle generations are just excitations of the basic family (the up and down quark, the electron, and the electron neutrino). It unifies quarks and leptons. It even offers an alternative to mass generation.
All advantages, you might think. The model is similar to the quark model which explains the structure of all known particles (but not the eventual structure of themselves). Yet when proposed, it meets a lot of resistance in the physics community.
Is this because the members want to stick to the traditional models? In particular, the Standard Model? Are they afraid to lose their jobs? Are they afraid of not being accepted or being frowned upon? What is it?

Comment: Physics question.

Comment: Maybe the scientific community does not agree on "the obvious advantages", in particular if lacking experimental evidence.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But there is. The muon-g2 experiment provides. Of course, there is no experimental evidence, but it *can* be obtained. The energy is not enough yet to arrive at the results. There is no evidence that it is not true either. Even the discovery of the Higgs particle doesn't prove the existence of the Higgs mechanism. I ask because it *solves* the puzzle of matter-antimatter asymmetry. It *solves* the question of why elementary particles have different masses. It *solves* the question of unification of the weak and EM forces. Etc.

Comment: @armand I asked about this already on the physics site. The question was considered non-mainstream and off-topic...

Comment: Is this theory able to explain all the experimentally verified predictions of the standard model? If so can you point to a source that mentions this?

Comment: @Hypnosifl It can even predict the decay of the proton. It explains *all* predictions of the standard model and it makes new ones that the standard model does not.

Comment: Can you point me to a source that confirms it reproduces all the predictions of the standard model?

Comment: @Hypnosifl If you study the theory (very simple combinatorics in principle) yo will see that all particle interactions can be accounted for. For example, the Higgs can decay (via two W's or Z's) into leptons and quarks (four of them). The Higgs is seen as the same combinations of rishons as are present in these quarks and leptons (say a positron an anti neutrino, an electron and a neutrino). The decay of the proton can be seen as an exchange of rishons between the quarks containing them.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Of course the exact potential that keeps the rishons together is not known (yet) and has to be determined by experiment. But basically the rishons have a color force with color charge (the known strong force) and a hyper color force (comparable with the strong force but much stronger), and of course the electric force (with electric charge). So the weak force is a residue force (as was the old strong force).

Comment: You still aren't giving me a source for the claim that the rishon model would reproduce *all* the tested quantitative predictions of the standard model (for example, the precise value of the [electron magnetic moment](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.06174.pdf), or other types of quantitative predictions like the ones discussed [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631070515000742) and [here](https://experts.illinois.edu/en/publications/measurements-of-inclusive-and-differential-cross-sections-of-comb)). Does this mean you haven't seen any physicists actually say this?

Comment: @Hypnosifl Okay then. Here is an example involving hyper color: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335715686_Calculation_of_the_Standard_Model_parameters_and_particles_based_on_a_SU4_preon_model

Comment: @Hypnosifl I think these calculations are not that important. It's the model itself that is compelling. Only two elementary, massless particles. Imagine that!

Comment: But a single example does not back up your earlier claim that "It explains *all* predictions of the standard model". If it hasn't been demonstrated to do that, I think this answers your original question--physicists do not accept theories based on their conceptual explanations of phenomena (Feynam disparaged this for ex.), but mainly based on predictive power. Though when exploring new theoretical possibilities, there is a role for intuition about whether a tentative model might be developed in a way to give more predictions, so some might see the rishon model as "promising" in that sense.

Comment: It explains *all* features phenomenologically. Mathematical details are unimportant in that case. If more attention was given to this theory (at the moment everybody is still trying to confirm the Standard model, over and over again, though the muon-g2 experiment is a strong hint for direct proof) there would have been more attention. If higher energy collisions become available the substructure will certainly appear. But why give it attention if there is not yet an observed structure? This is the attitude of most physicists today. They are pretty conservative. New physics is no good...

Comment: @Methadont - [Phenomenology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenomenology_(physics)) in physics refers to quantitative predictions, not qualitative or conceptual explanations--are you indeed saying the rishon model has been shown mathematically to reproduce all the experimentally tested quantitative predictions of the standard model, and if so, can you give a reference for this?

Comment: @Hypnosifl Before the arrival of the quark model, the properties of the standard model were determined by experiment only. The quarks didn't contribute anything. You must see the rishons in the same light (maybe even better because they offer an explanation of the masses of the standard model, that is an intituitively better one, as opposed to the Higgs mechanism; it even literally unifies energy and mass). Only when experimental evidence is found, things can get calculated

Comment: @Hypnosifl "In physics, phenomenology is the application of theoretical physics to experimental data by making quantitative predictions based upon known theories" There you go.

Comment: @Methadont "Before the arrival of the quark model, the properties of the standard model were determined by experiment only." The equations of the standard model certainly make predictions, of course the model itself has periodically been modified by new experimental discoveries, but the point is that each modification makes new quantitative predictions and also preserves the successful predictions of the past version, this was true when quantum chromodynamics (dealing with quarks) was incorporated, tests are mentioned at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics#Experimental_tests

Comment: So, if you like, my question about quantitative predictions can be rephrased to include the idea of including rishons in a new proposed modification to the standard model, rather than an alternative to it. But you still need a model that preserves all the old successful quantitative predictions, and makes new quantitative predictions that either can be or have been tested--the wikipedia quote you posted does specifically say "quantitative predictions", not just a new qualitative understanding of existing data.

Comment: @Hypnosifl What about the prediction that the weak force is a residual force (as the old meson mediated strong force), or the prediction that the Higgs particle is just a normal prtical field (so not a false vacuum field excitation), or what about the prediction that there is no matter/anti-matter asymmetry?

Comment: @Hypnosifl Maybe I should do the calculations myself...If the rishons are massles, and you vary the interaction strength this should be possible in principle. When the desired quark masses pop out, the models coupling strengths are the ones you need. The Planck length is still far removed from $10^{-18}$(m). Using QCD with the color charge replaced by the hyper color charge (or coupling strength). The interactions are identical in form (another advantage).

Comment: Those sound more like conceptual explanations rather than quantitative predictions, unless something like "the prediction that the weak force is a residual force" can be shown to lead to some specific numerical predictions about some experiment (like quantitative features of the pattern of tracks in a bubble chamber in some type of particle collision experiment), predictions which are not made by prior theories like the existing version of the standard model. Certainly if you think you can calculate new quantitative predictions from rishons that would be a worthwhile project.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I'll try, but I'm not sure how to do a non-perturbative calculation. Maybe a succession of perturbations? I think the model offers a better understanding, even if it hasn't made predictions yet (?). It has the potential to explain the masses (for example). The standard model offers no such explanation. I think the calculations made in this model aren't looked after for because most physicists are working inside the standard model system, so to speak. Focusing on some exotic theory will rob them from their bread.

Comment: @Hypnosifl The quark calculations offer values accessible to current technology and the rishon model doesn't say much about these values. The quark model is perfectly fit for these distances.  The rishon model is perfectly fit for smaller distances. Quarks as units for the "large", rishond for the small. It will be the last level too. Less than two elementary particles is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it's a quark-like model. The quark model predicts that bound states of quarks should have a measurable nonzero size, should contain substructure that is visible in [deep inelastic scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_inelastic_scattering), and should have a large mass because of the binding energy of the strong force. As the deep-inelastic-scattering article mentions, physicists were generally skeptical about the quark model until direct experimental evidence for it was seen.

No evidence has ever been found that the Standard Model's fundamental particles have a size or substructure. Furthermore, the more tightly bound the rishons are, the higher the binding energy needs to be; that should give the bound states an enormous mass, much larger than the hadrons, but some Standard Model fermions have tiny masses. The more stringent the other bounds get, the worse the mass problem gets.

Unifying the Standard Model particles and explaining their weird charges isn't as compelling as it sounds, because [GUTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory) also do that, while avoiding the problems of quark-like models. Physicists are suspicious of GUTs because there's no direct experimental evidence for any of them, but at least they don't seem to be ruled out by current data, as quark-like models seem to be.

If experiments ever suggest that a quark-like model is correct, then everyone will drop everything else and start working on them, but with the evidence as it stands, they seem like a dead end.

Comment: So the situation is exactly the same as the situation was before the discovery of quarks? Leaving the huge mass problem aside.

Answer (score 0):

The 2008 paper ['The Harari-Shupe preon model and nonrelativistic quantum phase space', Zenczykowski](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0223) shows there is some interest still. This 2018 paper uses the model: ['The Matter-Antimatter Asymmetry Problem', Robson](https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=82173). Both in prestigious journals. I'd consider [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preon#Rishon_model) pretty good billing, Wikipedia is typically very on-point about physics. And CERN are absolutely looking for quark substructure.

It takes graduate students a good chunk of their careers to get a deep enough understanding of these kind of theories to make head-way, that makes them very specialised. Doing a PhD in a kind of physics that might get binned or go nowhere is a big risk, in a discipline with few & extremely competitive funded places & teaching positions. I really recommend listening to Sean Carroll talk about his journey on his Mindscape podcast, like '[Are we moving beyond the standard midel](https://youtu.be/jHLfMXvQqX8)?' or '[Finding gravity in quantum mechanics](https://youtu.be/U3ACVQRSoHc)'. People in fundamental physics do gave to take risks in what they study, for Sean they paid off as he was ready with a deep understanding of General Relativity after decades when all the progress was in particle physics. He has further stuck his neck out to champion working on the fundamentals of quantum mechanics, an area basically considered 'discreditable' to work on as being a magnet for kooks. It takes the influence of thinkers & communicators like him, to help guide graduates into what specialisms to pursue.

Quantum-gravity is one of the biggest problems in physics, & that is what people are look for progress on in new theories - nothing from rishons about gravity, as I understand it. Then dark matter and dark energy: again, not providing candidates or mechanisms as far as I can find.. Explaining matter-antimatter assymetry in a new way is fine, but the current model is pretty compelling. If quarks are composite particles, preons should show up at CERN. That is the only way evidence will be found, & it's going to take time.

I always think it's funny that non-physicists think String Theory gets all the support and funding and prestige, when in fact nearly all leading physicists go out of their way to distance themselves from it because it's basically considered a dead field now. Like Susskind considered a foundational String Theorist. Fashions come & go. Quark substructure is definitely on the table, but it's not currently an exciting topic to work on.

Some related discussions about good theory-making, to bring this back on to a philosophical track:

[One big theory of Everything (TOE) or multiple "domain specific" theories?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/48143/one-big-theory-of-everything-toe-or-multiple-domain-specific-theories/51388#51388)

[Should viable philosophical theories not always be consistent with science?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/49539/should-viable-philosophical-theories-not-always-be-consistent-with-science/49555#49555)

[Why do people make theories without predictive power?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/78997/why-do-people-make-theories-without-predictive-power/79001#79001)

[Can a solid theory ever exist without any axioms?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/53556/can-a-solid-theory-ever-exist-without-any-axioms/56056#56056)

[How can a finite number of observations justify confidence in complex theories](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/73527/how-can-a-finite-number-of-observations-justify-confidence-in-complex-theories/73545#73545)

Comment: Very good answer! I think it's indeed the fact that it's no accepted point of view that stops most physicists. Luckily it's still being studied. If more elementary particles will be discovered, for sure all heads will turn! The decay of the proton is very easy to visualize in the context of rishons.

Comment: Where have you seen Susskind distance himself from string theory? Are you sure he wasn't just saying that the current mathematical formulation of string theory (perturbation theory etc.) cannot be the final one, which I gather has been a central idea of "M theory" since the 1990s? In [this 2017 paper for example](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.03040.pdf) he takes the reality of the higher-dimensional "bulk" space for granted and on p. 3 says "if the CFT coupling were too weak other microscopic bulk scales (such as the size of strings) would be large; a single string could fill the bulk space".

Comment: Also found that at [13 minutes into this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQAcLW6qdQY&t=780s) Susskind discusses some comments that seemed to say he wasn't a "believer" in string theory, he clarifies that he's talking about the "formal, mathematically rigorous structure" of string theory as it is now, he is unsure if the correct theory will be a "small modification" or a "big modification" of string theory (no suggestion it might just be completely the wrong track), and he still thinks it has great value as a theoretical laboratory for exploring questions in quantum gravity.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: It was at the beginning of a debate, where he was introduced as a string theorist. He immeduately objected, framing it as don't pigeon-hole him as 'a string theorist'. I still thought it was telling..

Comment: @Hypnosifl: I realised Susskind distanced himself like that when he was on the Mindscape podcast

Comment: Let me start by saying that I like this Carrol guy! Thanks for the link. What do you mean by"an area basically considered 'discreditable' to work on as being a magnet for kooks" kooks may need a magnet to hang their recipes on the fridge.

Comment: @Methadont: I blame these two https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Wigner_interpretation